# Why are the buttons shifted left?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Falling a Udemy tutorial on Node, React, Express.

He is using a Header and his code shifts the Login and Cart links to the far right. I have the same code as he does, but my links are not shifted to the far right. I am using the React-bootstrap per the tutorial. My code is the same?

[image]

```html
<header>
  <Navbar bg='dark' variant='dark' expand='lg' collapseOnSelect>
    <Container>
      <Navbar.Brand href='/'>BShop</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />
      <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
        <Nav className='ml-auto'>
          <Nav.Link href='/cart'>
            <i className='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>Cart
          </Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href='/login'>
            <i className='fas fa-user'></i>Login
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
  </Navbar>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using the latest bootstrap v5, which changed their `ml` and `mr` util classes to `ms` and `me`.

In, v5, left and right utils has been changed to `start(s)` and `end(e)`[1]. So, try replacing `ml-auto` to `ms-auto`.

Reference:

1. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities